# Linux open source 2d GUI engine comparable to WPF

Tags: linux, user-interface, 2d, graphic

I am looking for a 2d open source GUI engine on Linux, to eliminate our reliance on Windows. Our current application is written in C# + WPF, which is incredibly slow and costly. It is stopping us to do anything awesome. If there is anything in Linux that can offer what WPF could offer (easy to use designer, animations, layout and component controls, etc) I would rather rewrite my entire code base in C++/Java in Linux.

Qt is one option but I am a little bit worried about its support in the future, given recently Nokia fired the entire team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still suggest Qt. Even if Nokia destroys all of their support for it, Qt is under the LGPL. That means that the source will still be available and free (libre), and the KDE community will keep it going. They already are to a degree anyway. Also, although Qt is still C++, it is a very modified extension of C++ through the meta object compiler (`moc`), a special sort of preproccessor. I think you won't regret the choice to use Qt.

Of course, if you want to stay on C# and .NET, there is the open source Mono initiative, who are trying to create a drop in replacement for .NET and C# that is mostly compatible. I don't know if they support anything besides Win Forms, but there are bindings for almost every graphics lib out there, so you can use GTK (a binding called GTK#), Qt, WxWidgets, and a lot of other things.

Also, there are GNOME's Glib and GTK+, which are the other major interface libraries for Linux. They are C oriented, so you might have a harder time adapting your code though.

Comment: In fact the only reason we used C# at the first place was C# is the easiest language to control WPF. KDE is having some problem too recently but if they will continue to support Qt, Qt might be the best choice among all.

Comment: @Polymorpher: I definitely suggest Qt. The open source community will keep it going if they like it, and they like it. And KDE is going strong -- they have commercial support, are releasing like nobody's business, and have a lot of users since GNOME and Unity started upsetting people.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight):

> Silverlight implement a subset of the WPF APIs and is available on
>   Windows, MacOS X and through our own open source effort Moonlight it
>   is available on Linux and other Unix systems.
>
> Silverlight does not have all the capabilities of WPF, but both
>   technologies are converging API-wise.
>
> Silverlight can now be used outside of the browser, and Moonlight can
>   be configured to be used with the full .NET API outside of the
>   browser.

[more...](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)

Comment: Since Moonlight is basically a replicated Silverlight, and Silverlight is basically part of WPF, would performance be an issue? Has anyone compared the performance difference between Qt and Moonlight?